# MUI: The `fade` color utility was renamed to `alpha` to better describe its functionality. (material-table)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using material-table (npm latest v1.69.3) with MUI v5.0.6 since I need a editable table. I got this msg in my console.

[image]

It says import alpha but since fade is used in material-table which is a npm package I don't know what to do here.

What I want to know is why is this error occurring, how to get rid of this error and fix the issue.
Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`material-table` package is [not actively maintained](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/3044) anymore and currently it only supports MUI v4. There is a community fork [here](https://github.com/material-table-core/core) where you can use the material table [with MUI v5](https://github.com/material-table-core/core/issues/349) by installing the next version:

```
npm install @material-table/core@next
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: i just have to install that npm right? i did that. doesnt work :(

Comment: @ShakyaKarunathilake have a look at the working codesandbox in my answer. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/69783973-mui-the-fade-color-utility-was-renamed-to-alpha-to-better-describe-its-func-f75qp?file=/package.json) is the `package.json` file for reference.

Comment: can u please tell me whether "@types/react": "17.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.10", these two dependencies are required to fix this issue?

Comment: @ShakyaKarunathilake those packages add type definitions for react and react-dom if you're using typescript. It should not be related to the error you're having.

Comment: @ShakyaKarunathilake can you tell me what is working for you so I can include it in my answer?

Comment: I installed the npm package just like u told me. I never used a community fork before so took some time to get the idea of it. Installing the package and import the relevant components helped